# How do you enable better missing method errors on the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

This is probably obvious, but I'm not seeing how to do it. Take the following:

```
myobj.mymethod()
```

When this is executed in Node, I see really helpful errors like `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'mymethod'`. But in the browser, I usually see generic things like `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Is there any way for the browser to report more helpful errors like this?

Answer (score 0):

So I looked around a bit more, and it turns out you can overload `window.onerror`.  There's an [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers.onerror) on it.  You could possibly get the arguments passed to that handler, somehow check to see if the error matched what you are looking for, and then change the message.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that, but still not sure how. You can use `url`, `line`, and `column` to show the source code like Node does, but that still doesn't get you the **object** that produced the error for writing the `Object #<Object>` part.